# Strange Forbidden Access error after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, authentication, web-config

I get :

[image]

after I publish my website to the IIS server, straight after I press the login button with correct credentials. It works fine on my local machine and is supposed to transfer me to the `ControlPanel.aspx` page.

Login button code :

```
    protected void BtnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Username == txtUserName.Text && x.Password == txtPassword.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myalert", "alert('* invalid credentials, please try again');", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought it may have something to do with the web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ControlPanel.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Options.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="ControlPanel.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.csdl|res://*/db.ssdl|res://*/db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.***\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Portal;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked the user permissions on the folder where your application is deployed?

Comment: @KevinD. the logon.aspx is in the same folder and that shows fine. I did check and set full permissions to Everyone and still shows the same error.